# Can evaluations not be performed in a class property?

Tags: php

I have a `functions.php` file containing many variables and functions that I am needing to enclose in a class. I haven't worked much with OO PHP before and I am getting stopped dead with the simplest of problems. I extracted out a simple case, for explanation purposes:

```
class MyTestClass
{
    public $isTest = true;
    public $isLocalhost = ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "localhost");
}
```

I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE) in ... on line 8

The first line (`public $isTest = true;`) seems to work fine. Outside of a class, this works fine: `$isLocalhost = ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "localhost");`

Can evaluations not be performed in a class property? What is the simplest way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: better set this property in `__construct()` method! Or even better: make `isLocalhost` an actual method

Comment: YOu can't  declare variable in php like this `public $isLocalhost = ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "localhost");`

Comment: `public $isTest = true;` is evaluated on the compile time. The value of `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` cannot be evaluated on the compile time. Move the initialization of `$isLocalhost` in the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Comment: From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php): Declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make access modifier in class like below

```
class MyTestClass
{
    public $isTest;
    public $isLocalhost;
    function __construct() {
         $this->isTest = true;
         $this->isLocalhost = ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "localhost")?$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]:'';
    }
}
$MyTestClass= new MyTestClass();
echo $MyTestClass->isLocalhost; // Output : localhost
```

If variable has public keyword then you can access outside of class.

Comment: `$this->isLocalhost = ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "localhost")?$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]:'';`

Comment: Thanks so much, it works great now.